# Unable to decrypt/download KMS encrypted objects from S3 bucket in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Earlier today I tried granting an IAM user in `B` the ability to access objects in `A` via a bucket policy as well as updated the KMS policy for the CMK in `A` to permit `B` to use the CMK. Confirmed that each individual operation works

Using an account in `B`

```
aws kms encrypt --key-id 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:11111:key/KEYID' --plaintext 'hello world'

aws s3 cp localfile s3://bucket-in-a
```

Both operations work fine. However, when `B` tries to upload a file with server-side encryption to the bucket or tries to download an encrypted file, I receive an AccessDenied message. I'm pretty sure the role assumption route would work fine but was looking for a simpler alternative.

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied`

Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:user/USER"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

CMK Policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/ADMIN",
          "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:user/USER"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "kms:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, I think it's highly inadvisable to allow an external IAM user to have kms:* permissions. You may want to reduce this.

Comment: that's the purpose of encrypting data :) each account has its own master kms key. However the AccessDenied message doesn't reveal if the deryption failed (using wrong key) or policies or request parameters are wrong

Comment: You really don't want 3rd-party IAM users to disable, rotate, or schedule key deletions.

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure the role assumption route would work fine but was looking for a simpler alternative."*  That's actually a superior alternative in every way that I can think of... and really not especially complicated.  Simpler, in many ways, even.  When a principle from B uploads an object to a bucket owned by account A, account B is actually the object owner, which can complicate permissions... particularly if account C also needs to access the object, too.  If B assumes a role from A, that's all avoided.